# What is the best way to do an inline image sprite?

Tags: html, sprite

After some reasearch I found that I can stretch a transparent GIF to the sprite size and set the background to the sprite image with offset.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/6bT3j/embedded/result

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP//////zCH5BAEHAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="
    width="30" height="30" style=" background: -88px -223px 
        url('http://ssl.gstatic.com/gb/images/j_f11bbae9.png');"
>
```

Is this the best, cleanest way to go about creating an inline image sprite?

Comment: Why would you need to stretch the transparent gif?

Comment: I stretched the gif to equal the size of the sprited image. The gif is 1px by 1px traditionally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe my way as described above is the best way to load an image sprite.

I added only the CSS needed to view that sprite and left all other CSS in the StyleSheet where it belongs.

While the true source of the image is a transparent GIF whether you use an actual gif or the data equivalent in my example above the sprite image is set as the background and offset to reveal the needed sprite.

It makes it possible to use the img tag for it's intended purpose: such as the alt attribute, and the tag's default inline display.

A single image tag with certain inline css is a lot less html than anything else I have seen and semantic html can be added where needed.

Comment: Yes, but this requires two images (two http calls) rather than **one**, this actually degrades site performance more, and therefore defeats the object of the sprite. The amount of html, provided it is semantic, is irrelevant.

Comment: One single extra call for the entire page load since the sprite will reuse that 1px gif OR no extra calls if you use the data src method. Perhaps if I make an empty area the size of the largest sprite slice at the top left of the sprite then I could even use the sprite as the spacer. Good point, though.

Comment: The reuse isn't the issue it's the http call, your method defeats the object of the sprite.

Comment: You didn't read my comment above; there are two solutions to the extra http request problem.

Comment: Actually the only way to prevent the extra http request is using data src.

Answer (score 1):

Below is Google's homepage CSS Sprite (you'll see no transparent gif is required).

If the image has [semantic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_HTML) meaning, for example it's a logo or a picture central to an article then this is the best technique to use.

But if the image you're loading has no [semantic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_HTML) meaning e.g. it's a navigation image which is there for decoration only, then you might want to use [CSS to load the image](http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=447210) rather than an image tag.

> **Google CSS Sprite**

[image]

> **HTML**

```
<div class="nojsv" id="logocont" style="left: 0px; position: absolute; visibility: visible; ">
  <h1>
    <a id="logo" href="https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?hl=en" title="Go to Google Home">
      Google
        <img width="167" height="389" src="/images/nav_logo104.png" alt="">
    </a>
  </h1>
</div>
```

> **CSS**

```
#logo {
  display: block;
  height: 41px;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 114px;
}
```

Comment: Ok, this makes sense. The answer is Yes if it has semantic meaning otherwise use the existing structural html/css. 

I concur except when it is an inline image in a paragraph, which would make good use of the single image tag with inline CSS.

I think your example above is missing some CSS to offset the image.

Comment: @iambriansreed if you look at the google search results page, you'll see that no such css exists, but I can't quite figure out how the text is being hidden. I would say though that inline images, like the one in your example do not have semantic meaning.