# how to make an image occupy multiple div's at the same time

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to html and javascript so got stuck in something that might be simple, thanks in advance.
I have an image of say 140px by 140px size and I have 4 divs of size 70px by 70px each.
Div's are arranged as follows

```
div1|div2
div3|div4
```

There is no distance between the divs. I want to drag the image into the divs and since the image has an area equal to all 4 divs, I want the image to occupy all 4 divs simultaneously. Currently the image is occupying only one div and is merely obscuring others from view (when placed in div1) and juts out when placed in others.

here is my code

```
            function allowDrop(ev)
            {
                ev.preventDefault();
            }

            function drag(ev)
            {
                ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
                abc=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
            }

        function drop(ev)
        {

                if(abc="image4x4")
                {
                      ev.preventDefault();
                  var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
                                  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));

            }
        }
    </script>
    <style>
        .divclass0
        {
            height:200px;
            width:200px;
            border:1px solid;

        }
        .divclass
        {
            height:200px;
            width:200px;
            border:1px solid;
            margin-left:201px;
            margin-top:-202px
        }
        .divclass1
        {
            height:70px;
            width:70px;
            border:1px solid;

        }
        .divclass2
        {
            height:70px;
            width:70px;
            border:1px solid;

        }
        .imageclass
        {
            height:140px;
            width:140px;
        }
        .divclass1b
        {
            height:70px;
            width:70px;
            border:1px solid;
            margin-left:71px;
            margin-top:-72px;
        }
        .divclass2b
        {
            height:70px;
            width:70px;
            border:1px solid;
            margin-left:71px;
            margin-top:-72px;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="divclass0" id="div0" ondrop="drop(event)"; ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
        <img id="image4x4" class="imageclass" src="tree2.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
    </div>
    <div class="divclass" id="div0" ondrop="drop(event)"; ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
        <img id="image1x1" class="imageclass2" src="smiley3.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
    </div>
    <div class="divclass1" id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)"; ondragover="allowDrop(event)">

    </div>
    <div class="divclass1b" id="div1(b)" ondrop="drop(event)"; ondragover="allowDrop(event)">

    </div>

    <div class="divclass2" id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)"; ondragover="allowDrop(event)">

    </div>
    <div class="divclass2b" id="div2(b)" ondrop="drop(event)"; ondragover="allowDrop(event)">

    </div>
```

actually the div's are supposed to be inventory units for the player in my game. i want to limit the no of inventory items sort of like in the game called commandos2(men of courage) player inventory

Comment: Show your code so far. (create a [JSFidddle](http://jsfiddle.net/))

Comment: You need to cut your image into 4 pieces, otherwise just use 1 div with the correct dimensions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to do an inline image sprite?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9642198/what-is-the-best-way-to-do-an-inline-image-sprite)

Comment: you can put all 4 div in big one with size of image and set image as backgound

Answer (score 3):

This technique is called "[CSS image sprites](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp)". You load one big image and then use it as background in several `div`s which have a fixed size.

Use the CSS `background-position:x y;` to cut out the part of the image that you want to be visible in each `div`.

Answer (score 1):

Create a div around all 4 divs give this `position:relative;`
Then you can add an image and give this `position:absolute;`

Like so:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="div1">
        <img src="http://s9.postimg.org/o4vm98saz/test.png" alt="Test image" />
    </div>
    <div class="div2"></div>
    <div class="div3"></div>
    <div class="div4"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    position:relative;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
.div1, .div2, .div3, .div4 {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    float:left;
}
.div1 img {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put all divs in one div and put your image as a background to this div. I don't think there is a need for a sprite.